# Gitlab CI - composer install on private repo

Tags: git, symfony, composer-php, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm trying to setup Gitlab CI for a project I'm working on (PHP - Symfony 4 / MySQL). I've got the `.gitlab-ci.ym`l file created with the necessary steps to prepare a Docker image. One of the steps is to run `composer install` - this should normally install a bunch of linked code, a few of which come from private repositories (also stored on Gitlab).

I'm trying to work out the current best practice for allowing the Gitlab CI runner to clone this code from it's private repo. I see reference in other Stack Overflow posts to the `${CI_JOB_TOKEN}` variable, but seem to be missing the connecting bits of information to make it work - for example, do I need to modify the private repos to access this variable as a deploy token somehow, or does this happen automatically as Gitlab is cloning code from it's own servers?

Does anyone have a complete example of a `.gitlab-ci.yml` file that can clone code from a private repo using composer? If it's relevant, there are 4 private repos I need to clone, and will need to have the same CI setup for many projects that rely on these based libraries.

Answer (score 10):

I managed to resolve this after reading this page a few more times - https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/new_ci_build_permissions_model.html

It mentions that the user that pushes the code is the user that runs the CI task as. Using this knowledge and the `CI_JOB_TOKEN` variable that is automatically available, I added the following to my `before_script`:

```
git config --global url."https://gitlab-ci-token:${CI_JOB_TOKEN}@gitlab.com/".insteadOf "git@gitlab.com:"
```

...and then in my `composer.json`, added the list of repositories I wanted to use (using the `"repositories": []` keys, as this allowed me to force them to use https to checkout instead of ssh that I use locally.

This combination now allows me to run the CI tasks and pull code from the private repositories without permissions issues - no need for deploy keys or tokens.

Comment: Thank you for filling-in the gaping holes in the GitLab documentation.

Comment: Do you now have the complete .gitlab-ci.yml file you were seeking to share? :)

Comment: Sorry, I think I abandoned it shortly after and didn't fully complete it.

Answer (score 0):

has any of you managed to get to the bottom of this?

I managed to get git to replace the url for the repo set in composer.json (with the `git config --global url...` command) but now I get an auth error:

```
remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied                                                                                                                                                         
  fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://xxx.xxxx.xx:4043/xxxx/repo-shared.git/'
```

I just can't help noticing that the `gitlab-ci-token:${CI_JOB_TOKEN}@` is missing in the error... any idea?